# Java application when deployed works on 8.5.20 but give java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ie null connection on tomcat 8.5.75

Tags: java, tomcat8

I am trying to upgrade version of Tomcat from 8.5.20 to 8.5.75. The application works completely fine on 8.5.20, but the same application gives me null connection in other version.

I am using Java 8. My database is Oracle 19c and I am using ojdbc8.jar. The connection details are mentioned in Tomcat conf folder in context.xml file. Am I missing anything here?
following is My log file stackTrace

```
18-Apr-2022 18:47:14.594 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing database connection
    at de.wizardry2.util.Wzd2BrokerRepository.getBrokerInstance(Wzd2BrokerRepository.java:171)
    at de.wizardry.WzdPoBroker.getBrokerInstance(WzdPoBroker.java:98)
    at com.volkswagenag.dqm.businessmodel.portal.UserBroker.getInstance(UserBroker.java:122)
    at com.volkswagenag.dqm.businessmodel.portal.UserBroker.getInstance(UserBroker.java:38)
    at com.volkswagenag.dqm.importer.servlet.UserAuthentication.login(UserAuthentication.java:201)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:252)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:266)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.volkswagenag.dqm.importer.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:847)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1680)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace of the exception you get.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel please check the stacktrace, I thought it wont be of much use.

Comment: #1 How are you connecting to the database? #2 Is this error at the startup or when some form is submitted? #3 As Mark Rotteveel said, if you want help, create a simple form with faces in the new tomcat and tell us if you was capable of reproduce the error.

Comment: @JRichardsz once deployed I run the application locally, when I Enter login credentials in the login form it throws this error.

Comment: As a recommendation, you can try to identify exact version of Tomcat on which your application is failing and then take a look at Tomcat's changelog